# Unknown site using our analytics code

Tags: google-analytics

I did a review on our google analytics this morning and realised that we have a unknown site using our analytics code; this is because they copied our site design and even used our source code letter for letter.

Is there a way to filter out this site from our google analytics as there data is essentially scewing our data.

Cheers

Comment: Unknown as in "not yours" or unknown as in "you have no idea what domain we're talking about"? If you can find the site, contact the site owners and let them know that stealing source code isn't OK.

Comment: Wow. Copying a web site is already low. Not even bothering to change the analytics code is... I don't know what to say

Comment: i know the domain and its not ours, i think we will have to get a C&D order.

Comment: Google may be willing to throw away the bad data for you; maybe they can drop data based on netblock.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter out their data.

First, you can figure out what the domain is by adding the 'Hostname' secondary dimension in your content view. Once you have a handle on what hostnames its using (www.thief.com, thief.com, subdomain.thief.com, or whatever).

Create the filter (Instructions here: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55494)

Set the filter to exclude traffic from the thief's hostname.

[alt text http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/15648633/1x0Cbj.Screen%20shot%202010-08-13%20at%2011%3A43%3A42.png](http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/15648633/1x0Cbj.Screen%20shot%202010-08-13%20at%2011%3A43%3A42.png)

(This thread has some details on how this implemented: http://groups.google.com/group/analytics-help-basics/browse_thread/thread/051be84cfb20338a?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

@yahelc , while your instructions are OK if you look at documentation, this filter often doesn't work.

I recommend to use
Custom Filter / Exclude filter / Filter field : Hostname , where can use a regexp pattern

To test your pattern, Go in Visitors / Network Properties / Hostname, and give it try in the filter box